# Sql query to return one single record per each combination in a table

Tags: sql, combinations

I need the result for every combination of (from_id, to_id) which has the minimun value and the loop matching a criteria.

So basically I need the loop that has the minimun value. e.g. From A to B i need the minimun value and the loop_id .

The table has the following fields:

```
value     from_id   to_id     loop_id
-------------------------------------

2.3         A         B          2

0.1         A         C          2

2.1         A         B          4

5.4         A         C          4
```

So a result will be:

```
value     from_id   to_id     loop_id
-------------------------------------

2.1         A         B          4

0.1         A         C          2
```

I have tried with the following:

```
SELECT t.value, t.from_id, t.to_id,t.loop_id
FROM myresults t 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT min(m.value), m.from_id, m.to_id, m.loop_id
     FROM myresults m where m.loop_id % 2 = 0
     GROUP BY m.from_id, m.to_id, m.loop_id
) x
   ON  (x.from_id = t.from_id and x.to_id=t.to_id and x.loop_id=t.loop_id )
   AND x.from_id = t.from_id and x.to_id=t.to_id and x.loop_id=t.loop_id
```

But it is returning all the loops.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the loop_id from the inner derived table and therefore also the join to the outer query. Then it will return the minimum value for each combination and in the outer query you can find out the appropriate loop_id.

Comment: Hi Kaj, do you have a example of that query? Thanks

Comment: @baboso how about this query. `SELECT min(value) as value, from_id, to_id
from myresults
group BY from_id,to_id`

Comment: @viswanathan-iyer your query will return allm the loops. Also this wont work: SELECT min(value) as value, from_id, to_id, loop_id from myresults where loop_id % 2 = 0 group BY from_id,to_id,loop_id

Comment: @baboso then which loop_id you want?

Comment: @viswanathan-iyer I need the loop that has the minimun value.
From A to B i need the minimun value and the loop_id

Comment: @baboso: I'm on a phone so code formatting tediously slow. The answer from njr gets you the rows that you're interested in (equivalent to your query but without loop_id like I said). But you don't want loop_id as part of the selection because then it'll retun all rows. So instead you use it as a derived table - as you have in your question - and join back to the table using from_id, to_id and value. In the main select statement you then add loop_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the problem this will work:

```
SELECT  t.value, t.from_id, t.to_id, t.loop_id
FROM    MyResults t
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  From_ID, To_ID, MIN(Value) [Value]
            FROM    MyResults
            WHERE   Loop_ID % 2 = 0
            GROUP BY From_ID, To_ID
        ) MinT
            ON MinT.From_ID = t.From_ID
            AND MinT.To_ID = t.To_ID
            AND MinT.Value = t.Value
```

However, if you had duplicate values for a From_ID and To_ID combination e.g.

```
value     from_id   to_id     loop_id
-------------------------------------

0.1         A         B          2

0.1         A         B          4
```

This would return both rows.

If you are using SQL-Server 2005 or later and you want the duplicate rows as stated above you could use:

```
SELECT  Value, From_ID, To_ID, Loop_ID
FROM    (   SELECT  *, MIN(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY From_ID, To_ID) [MinValue]
            FROM    MyResults
        ) t
WHERE   Value = MinValue
```

If you did not want the duplicate rows you could use this:

```
SELECT  Value, From_ID, To_ID, Loop_ID
FROM    (   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY From_ID, To_ID ORDER BY Value, Loop_ID) [RowNumber]
            FROM    MyResults
        ) t
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: From A to B the min(value) is 2.1 and the loop_id is 4.
Your query is returning the worng value and loop_id for the connection A-B

Comment: Apolgies, I misunderstood the criteria. I think my edit will have sorted this.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this a lot more simply?

```
SELECT
  from_id,
  to_id,
  MIN(value)
FROM
  myresults
WHERE
  loop_id % 2 = 0
GROUP BY
  from_id,
  to_id
```

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

EDIT: To include loop_id

```
SELECT
  m2.from_id,
  m2.to_id,
  m2.value,
  m2.loop_id
FROM
  myresults m2 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
      m1.from_id,
      m1.to_id,
      MIN(m1.value)
    FROM
      myresults m1
    WHERE
      m1.loop_id % 2 = 0
    GROUP BY
      m1.from_id,
      m1.to_id) minset
  ON
        m2.from_id = minset.from_id
    AND m2.to_id = minset.to_id
    AND m2.value = minset.value
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to get also the loop_id. So this wont work:

SELECT
  from_id,
  to_id,
  MIN(value),
  loop_id
FROM
  myresults
WHERE
  loop_id % 2 = 0
GROUP BY
  from_id,
  to_id,
  loop_id

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the loop_id in the results. Sorry, you're right. Will update...

Comment: See my comment on the question - this gets the right subset of rows but the OP also wants to see loop_id. So you need an outer query to display that but not using it in identifying the relevant rows

Comment: @baboso: You didn't specify which rdbms you are using. If you are on a later version of SQL Server for example you can simplify this a lot by using OUTER APPLY

Comment: Hi Your query is working, but unfortunately is returning duplicate rows with different loop_id in case the value is the same. How can I filter your query to return just one row (for example max lopp_id) in case the value is duplicated